# Why is this `*invalid type` instead of `*Games`?

Tags: go, analysis

If you run the analysis package here: https://github.com/frederikhors/iss-goland-invalid-type with:

```
go run ./analysis
```

it will print:

```
field.Name: id - field.Type: string
field.Name: name - field.Type: string        
field.Name: games - field.Type: *invalid type
```

What I don't understand is why I'm having `*invalid type` instead of `*Games`?

#### Code

- analyis/main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "go/types"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/packages"
)

func main() {
    playerModel := LoadPackage("./player.go")

    var playerStruct *types.Struct

    for _, entity := range playerModel.Types.Scope().Names() {
        if entity == "Player" {

            playerStruct = GetStruct(entity, playerModel)

            break
        }
    }

    for i := 0; i < playerStruct.NumFields(); i++ {
        field := playerStruct.Field(i)

        println("field.Name: " + field.Name() + " - field.Type: " + field.Type().String())
    }
}

func LoadPackage(path string) *packages.Package {
    const mode = packages.NeedTypes |
        packages.NeedName |
        packages.NeedSyntax |
        packages.NeedFiles |
        packages.NeedTypesInfo |
        packages.NeedTypesInfo |
        packages.NeedModule

    cfg := &packages.Config{Mode: mode}

    pkgs, err := packages.Load(cfg, path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return pkgs[0]
}

func GetStruct(structName string, pkg *packages.Package) *types.Struct {
    foundStruct := pkg.Types.Scope().Lookup(structName)

    if foundStruct == nil {
        return nil
    }

    res, _ := foundStruct.Type().Underlying().(*types.Struct)

    return res
}
```

- player.go:

```golang
type Player struct {
    id    string
    name  string
    games *Games
}
```

- games.go:

```golang
package main

type Games struct {
    wins   []string
    losses []string
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you should use native types package. Golang comes with "reflect" package that allows you do do anything you want with types, much easier. Do you really need genericity with what you want to do though?

Comment: You are loading a single file with `LoadPackage("./player.go")` and the `Games` type is not declared in that file. Use `LoadPackage(".")`.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois can I read the file with reflection?

Comment: @mkopriva you're right. It works.

Comment: Anyways I suggest that you use your "player" package as a dependency instead of loading it each time, you are loosing interest of go performance. You should just recompile your program when you change it.

Comment: @BenjaminBarrois I don't understand. I'm not building anything. I'm using the analysis package to static analyze the main one. Is it possible to use reflection for this too?

Comment: @mkopriva can you answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @FredHors as long as what you want to do is to analyse Go source code, then doing what you're already doing is the correct approach. Reflection is of no relevance for that.

Comment: Yes you are right, I thought the final purpose of your program was to use Player model, not just analyse it. If so indeed reflection is not the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are explicitly loading *only* a single file with `LoadPackage("./player.go")`. And that file is *not* the one in which the `Games` type is declared. To load information on all types of a package you need to load the whole package.

You need to use `LoadPackage(".")`.